# Search Outlook Undeliverable Bounce Report

Tags: vba, email, outlook, report

I have undeliverable emails in a folder. I am trying to pull out the intended recipient's email address by searching the message.

I have some VBA code that works on regular emails, but undeliverable's are Outlook "Report Items". The search function is coming back empty and after a lot of research, it seems "Report Items" do not have a "body" that can be searched.

The email address in all the error reports are in the format:

> (xxxxxx@xxxxxx.com)

Code which works on mail items.

```vb
Sub Undeliver()

On Error Resume Next
Set myOlApp = Outlook.Application
Set mynamespace = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
 
'Selects the current active folder to use
Set myfolder = myOlApp.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder

'creates excel spreadsheet where data will go
Set xlobj = CreateObject("excel.application")
xlobj.Visible = True
xlobj.Workbooks.Add

'names column a row 1 "email" and column b row 1 "else"
xlobj.Range("a" & 1).Value = "Email"
xlobj.Range("b" & 1).Value = "Else"

'loops through all the items in the current folder selected
For I = 1 To myfolder.Items.Count
    Set myitem = myfolder.Items(I)

    'selects the body of the current email being searched
    msgtext = myitem.Body

    'searches the body for the first open parentheses and first close
    'parentheses and copies the value in between into an array
    delimtedMessage = Replace(msgtext, "(", "###")
    delimtedMessage = Replace(delimtedMessage, ")", "###")

    'splits the array up into two pieces
    messageArray = Split(delimitedMessage, "###")
    
    'this inputs the values of the array into my excel spreadsheet
    xlobj.Range("a" & I + 1).Value = messageArray(1)
    xlobj.Range("b" & I + 1).Value = messageArray(2)
Next I

End Sub
```

How can I access the message part of the report for searching purposes?

Comment: (I removed "Solved" from your title. Since you accepted an answer, that is the proper indication  for others with a similar question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I ended up going with involved converting the body of the message back to Unicode and then searching for what I needed. This ended up being very simple to implement.

Here is my finished, working code for future reference. I ended up adding a progress bar to monitor where it was in the code. It unfortunately runs fairly slow but it gets the job done.

Hopefully this helps someone in the future!

```
On Error Resume Next
Set myOlApp = Outlook.Application
Set mynamespace = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Set xlobj = CreateObject("excel.application")
xlobj.Visible = True
xlobj.Workbooks.Add

xlobj.Range("a" & 1).Value = "Email"
xlobj.Application.displayStatusBar = True

For I = 1 To myOlApp.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.Items.Count
    Set myitem = myOlApp.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.Items(I)
    msgtext = StrConv(myitem.Body, vbUnicode)

    delimtedMessage = Replace(msgtext, "mailto:", "###")
    delimtedMessage = Replace(delimtedMessage, "</a><br>", "###")
    messageArray = Split(delimtedMessage, "###")

    xlobj.Range("a" & I + 1).Value = Split(messageArray(1), """")(0)
    xlobj.Application.StatusBar = "Progress: " & I & " of " & myOlApp.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.Items.Count & Format(I / myOlApp.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.Items.Count, " 0%")
Next I

xlobj.Application.displayStatusBar = False
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is always [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-customize/problem-in-vba-reading-text-from-body-of-out-of/1d8ca369-a4c0-41da-9d28-3f490de3ed8c) solution.

The gist is that ReportItem.Body returns an unreadable string, so this solution saves the ReportItem as a text file, then parses the text file. Its not exactly elegant, but it should work.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This solution was interesting but at the bottom of the forum, there was another idea which I used to allow this to work out. Thanks!